# stop event after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am firing an event when im at a special scrollposition with [jquery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview). it works by adding classes if an element is in the viewport. in my script im saying the following

```
    var $BG = $('#BG')
$('#BG').bind('inview', function (event, visible) 
{
        if (visible == true) {
        $(this).addClass("inview");

        } else {

        $(this).removeClass("inview");
        }
    });

   if($BG.hasClass("inview")){

        $('#diagonal').css('left',0)
        $('#diagonal').css('top',0)

    }
```

but it fires the .css events again and again, but i want them to fire only at the first time the #BG gets the "inview" class.
thanks ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some var who tells if it has been fired or not :

```
var $BG = $('#BG'), firedInView = false;

$BG.bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if(!firedInView) {
        firedInView = true; //set to true and it won't be fired
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind the event handler using jQuery **unbind method** or use **one method** to handle event at most once.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.one()` instead `.bind()`:

```
$('#BG').one('inview',
```

Comment: unfortunatly i need the bind method, because i have lots of other div layers which lose the inview class when out of viewport! it would be nice if it would work only for the .css method! but it doesnt...

Answer (score 0):

I am going on the assumption that you would like to remove the styles on diagonal when #BG is out of view?

I'd split this into two listeners

```
//If bg does not have class inview, addClass if it is visible
$('body').on('inview', '#BG:not(.inview)', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        $(this).addClass("inview");
        $('#diagonal').css({'left': 0, 'top': 0});
    }
});

//If bg does has class inview, removeClass if it is invisible
$('body').on('inview', '#BG.inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == false) {
        $(this).removeClass("inview");
        $('#diagonal').css({'left': 'auto', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
});
```